# Find Duplicate rows in sql

Tags: sql

I want to find duplicate if there is duplicate in whole row via SQL. How to find here 2 rows with all values having duplicates like

**Data set**

```
id employee_name     dept  Dept_name
1    Abhijit         10    Physics
1    Abhijit         10    Physics
2    Debjit          20    Chemis
3    partha          30    Maths
```

**Result set**

```
id employee_name     dept  Dept_name
1    Abhijit         10    Physics
1    Abhijit         10    Physics
```

Comment: Do a self join on all fields.

Comment: Refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694263/filtering-duplicates-in-a-table-without-a-primary-key

Answer (score 5):

You can use having count(*) >1 grouping by your cols

```
select id, employee_name ,    dept,  Dept_name
from my_table 
group by  id, employee_name ,    dept,  Dept_name
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple group by and count based filter in having clause

```
Select id, employee_name, dept, dept_name
From your_table
Group by id, employee_name, dept, dept_name
Having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: You probably have whitespace or non printing character in your string. Otherwise the above solution should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Self join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

```
  SELECT a.* from employees a, employees b WHERE a.id = b.id and a.employee_name = b.employee_name and a.dept = b.dept;
```

dept_name probably it the same for the deps with the same id, so no need to include it in where clause

Comment: I have 27 columns in my table.self-join is not possible

Comment: someone please help

Comment: You should use an id/discriminator column(s) which will be your primary key and guarantee that the two rows that have the same value in that column are indeed duplicates. If such a relation can be inferred from your data, then it's sufficient to join just on it. In this concrete example the `id` field looks like a good candidate.

Comment: can you imagine how much join conditions I have to write?there are 27

Comment: can anyone tell me the answer?